# paintComponent() conditional

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, documentlistener

and here's my problem:
Traffic is a JTextArea where I insert text coming from a serial port and I did Implement a DocumentListener:

Java Code:

```
 Traffic.getDocument (). AddDocumentListener (new MyDocumentListener ());
```

the JTextArea "Traffic" show me what I want and the programs runs  Without any problems.
Now what I want to do is to act upon what have been inserted (only on the event of insert) line by line (that's what the tests are for), I'll give an example:

==> When I recieve "ON-HOOK" I put an image in the JPanel of a phone on hook if I recieve "OFF-HOOK" I put an image in the JPanel of a phone off hook and the list goes ...

I did not undrestand how to do that, how to call paintComponent when i want and make it draw what I want since I can only do graphic operation in the paintComponent ().
And this is the class for the DocumentListener:

```
  protected class MyDocumentListener  extends JPanel implements javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
{
 @Override
   public void changedUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
     // text has been altered in the textarea

     }

 @Override
  public void insertUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) 
  {
         // text has been added to the textarea 
     try { 

         if  (!Traffic.getText(Traffic.getLineStartOffset(Traffic.getLineCount()-1),Traffic.getLineEndOffset(Traffic.getLineCount()-1)-Traffic.getLineStartOffset(Traffic.getLineCount()-1)).contains(">>"))
         {

           if (Traffic.getLineCount()  == (lastreplace + 2) ) 
           {
               System.err.println(Traffic.getText(Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace),Traffic.getLineEndOffset(lastreplace) - Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace)));
            lastreplace +=1;

            }


          else
          {
            System.err.println(Traffic.getText(Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace),
                         Traffic.getLineEndOffset(lastreplace) - 
                                 Traffic.getLineStartOffset(lastreplace)));
          }
       }
        Traffic.setCaretPosition(Traffic.getDocument().getLength());

     } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(TrafficSerialPort.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

 }

 @Override
 public void removeUpdate(javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent e) {
   // text has been removed from the textarea

 }

}
```

I tried to use a method called `"PortArchitecture (..)"` will draw what I want and I use `getGraphics()` but I was told that it should not be used `paintComponent()` and now I'm really stuck please help.

Comment: 1) *"I want a entant the data"*  What does 'entant' mean?  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 4) What is your question?

Comment: done and thanks Andrew hope it's clear now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wouldn't do that in a document listener. You already have some method which updates the JTextAea when a line is read from the serial port. I would change the displayed image in this same method:

```
private void lineReceivedFromSerialPort(String line) {
    traffic.append(line);
    updateImage(line);
}
```

And to change the image, I wouldn't use `paintComponent()` at all. Simply have a JLabel somwewhere in your panel, and when a line is received, load the appropriate image icon and set it to the label:

```
private void updatImage(String line) {
    ImageIcon iconToDisplay = null;
    if (line.equals("ON-HOOK")) {
        iconToDisplay = phoneOnIcon;
    }
    else if (line.equals("OF-HOOK")) {
        iconToDisplay = phoneOffIcon;
    }
    ...
    imageLabel.setIcon(iconToDisplay);
}
```

Comment: thanks but I need to put the image in a JPanel cause when all transmission or Traffic from the serial port stops I will have a complete picture.What I want to obtain is an architecture of telephone network that's why I can not devide what I'm drawing and there isn't only images but also Strings and Lines that I need to draw on the JPanel.

Comment: Then each time you receive a line, change the state of the data that must be drawn, and invoke repaint(). In the paintComponent() method, read the data, and paint it.

Comment: thanks for the quick response but how will I change the state of the data? could you give me an example please!

Comment: I have added `graphicPanel.repaint()` to `insertUpdate` and added also `paintComponent()` to `MyDocumentListener` class but still dosn't work, the `paintComponent()` isn't even called.